# Windows Mobile 6 Tabstrip Control Equivalent?

Tags: windows-mobile

Is there a TabStrip-like control available for Windows Mobile 6?

I'd like to build multiple forms (or multiple views on a single form) and have some sort of tabstrip toggle between them.  However, i don't see anything in the toolbox that could support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/136) with a sample project for creating a tab control in windows mobile.